# gedit - FTP editing keep alive

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, gedit, keep-alive

I'm using gedit with Ubuntu to edit files through FTP.
I have bookmarked a FTP connection with the Ubuntu integrated functionnality (Connect to Server)
I can use it to edit files with gedit, but I didn't find a way to set any timeout or keep alive option.
So I have to refresh a Nautilus page on my bookmark to awake the connection each time.

What can I do ?

Comment: you'd be better asking at http://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using FileZilla is ok for a one-time transfer. The problem is that once you get used to how easy it is to edit files over a mounted network connection, applications like FileZilla are not an option. In fact, it would probably double or triple the time it takes to jump on a server and edit a quick file.

You are correct in saying there is no keep alive option in the gvfsd-ftp package. At least not one I can find. I did however find a simple bash script that would help out.

```
#!/bin/bash
while true 
do
    ls ~/.gvfs/ftp* &> /dev/null
    sleep 15 
done
```

No credit for me. I found this posted at [launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/410288)

Just run it at startup. On ubuntu you can just chmod a+x and run it as a startup app. Since there is a sleep timer, obviously you wouldn't want to run it multiple times in cron.

Answer (score 1):

The following code has worked wonders for gedit-ing via nautilus ftp for ubuntu 13.04 and ubuntu 14.04 (originally from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/605340/ubuntu-13-04-how-to-keep-nautilus-ftp-connection-alive) and [here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/usingkeepalive.html))

edit:

*/etc/sysctl.conf*

add these lines:

```
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time = 60
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl = 5
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes = 6
```

save and reboot system.

Comment: Your information is correct. See also  https://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/usingkeepalive.html. `# echo 600 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_time  # echo 60 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_intvl  # echo 20 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_probes`

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to write a custom Nautilus cript. Check this [SourceForge](http://g-scripts.sourceforge.net/faq.php) page.

Alternatively, you could use FileZilla and set gedit as the default editor. When FileZilla detect that you have saved a file, it will automatically update the FTP server.

Answer (score 0):

## Support for FTP and SFTP

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
    #10.10 and earlier
    ls /run/user/$UID/gvfs/ftp* &> /dev/null
    #for SFTP
    ls /run/user/$UID/gvfs/sftp* &> /dev/null
    #11.04+
    ls /run/user/$UID/gvfs/FTP* &> /dev/null
    #for SFTP
    ls /run/user/$UID/gvfs/SFTP* &> /dev/null
    sleep 15
done
```